# Unity 2d collision detection c# combat

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I wrote some code to detect object collision with an enemy but I am having some trouble piecing together several pieces of code into one. The idea of the code is to start combat between the player and an enemy and reduce the enemy's health randomly from 5 to 10 damage every 1.5 seconds.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerAttack : MonoBehaviour {
        float playerDamage;
    float attackTimer;
    bool playerCollide;
    public GameObject Slime;
    public float enemyCurrentHealth;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        attackTimer = 1.5f;
        enemyCurrentHealth = 100.0f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        OnCollsionEnter2D();
        if ( playerCollide )
        {
            if ( attackTimer == 1.5f )
            {
                playerDamage = Random.Range(5.0f,10.0f);
                enemyCurrentHealth -= playerDamage;
            }
            else if ( attackTimer <= 0.0f ) 
            {
                attackTimer = 1.5f;
            }
            attackTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if ( enemyCurrentHealth <= 0 )
            Destroy (gameObject.tag == "Slime");
            enemyCurrentHealth = 100.0f;
    }

    public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
            playerCollide = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What doesn't work? And do you want to have the line `enemyCurrentHealth = 100.0f;` to be part of the if statement two lines above? Your indentation indicates that but then you need to use curly braces `{}` (in my opinion a good idea to always use them anyway).

Comment: OnCollisionEnter2D(); brings up some errors which is the main problem since I don't know what to put for the arguements

Comment: now its if ( enemyCurrentHealth <= 0 )
  {
   Destroy(Slime);
   enemyCurrentHealth = 100.0f;
   playerCollide = false;
  }

Comment: You don't need to call OnCollisionEnter2D() on the Update method, the collision check is automatically made every frame

Comment: Can I post this answer?

Comment: Now it won't detect player and slime collisions after I gave them 2D Box Colliders.  There is no material but I can't use imported standard assets.